# query a value from CSV and get the count of that value from another CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe requirement were I need to get each value from one CSV1 and look for the count of occurrences of that value in a different CSV.

```
Ex - CSV1 

Category - ColumnName
HTTP
DISK
APACHE
IIS
SQL

EX - CSV2
Category - ColumnName
HTTP
HTTP
DISK
DISK
DISK
APACHE
IIS
IIS
ISS
SQL
```

I need to output as below

```
Category Count
HTTP      2
DISK      3
APACHE    1
IIS       3
SQL       1
```

I tried below -

```
df2['cat'] = df2['Category'].map(df1.set_index('Category'))
df2 = df2['cat'].value_counts().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
```

Not giving result as expected. Please help me with any pointers.

Comment: What does your result look like? How is it different than the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on column to get the count of values appeared in that column. Then use [pandas.Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map values of Series.

```py
df1['count'] = df1['Category'].map(df2['Category'].value_counts())
```

```
print(df1)

  Category  count
0     HTTP      2
1     DISK      3
2   APACHE      1
3      IIS      2
4      SQL      1
```

Comment: What if word in df1 is not found in df2 ?  Would it be better to also add `.fillna(0)` at the end ?

Comment: @SeaBean Then the count for missing word is NaN. Maybe it is better to fill it with 0 but OP doesn't claim that.

Comment: Your choice then but it's common to make missing item count as 0 rather than leave as NaN.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh is there a way, I can just copy the count as a column to CSV. I dont need category to be copied as I have that already pre-poulated in a CSV in same order, I just need the count value as a colum to be added with Column name as count.

Comment: @goe It's out of my knowledge then. Because to write to file, Python offers mainly three modes, `r`, `w` and `a`. There seems no mode for appending row by row.